# How to pass data to clean method in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am struggeling with passing an "external" parameter to my custom clean method.

Except of the identifier, I pass everything using the form. The identifier comes from the URL. 
I need to use the identifier in addition to the form stuff.

Here is my code:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    identifier = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()


class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry

    def clean(self):
        try:
            Entry.objects.get(
                identifier=THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO FILL,
                description=self.cleaned_data['description'],
                name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'We already have an entry with the same credentials!'))
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return self.cleaned_data
```

VIEW:

```
def addEntry(request, identifier):

    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=identifier)

    if request.method == "POST":
        entryForm = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if entryForm.is_valid():
            entry = entryForm.save(commit=False)
            entry.identifier = identifier
            entry.save()
        else:
            entryForm = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
...
```

So I am missing the part where I can add the identifier to the clean method.

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: do you have to validate the identifier ? (I guess not ?? )

Comment: One way would be to pass the identifier in as a HiddenField on your form, which you could pick up in cleaned_data.

Comment: I have to validate the identifier, as the combination (this is just demo code) is important for me. 

I use crispy forms and not sure how I can create a hidden field with a given parameter with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass it in from the view when you instantiate the form. The usual pattern is like this:

```
class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.identifier = kwargs.pop('identifier', None)
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        try:
            Entry.objects.get(
                identifier=self.identifier...
```

and in the view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    entryForm = EntryForm(data=request.POST, identifier=identifier)
```

Comment: You need to add `self` as a parameter to your init